# react & axios : login api doesn't get cookie

Tags: reactjs, authentication, cookies, axios

I used axios, customHook in react to make login.
I got status code 200, but I can't get cookie from Api. Api should send me cookie.

[provisional header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90KjC.jpg)

I think the provisional header there is the problem, so I checked extension, and used no-cache in developer tool.
[checked no-cache in developer tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKE3a.jpg)

Now there are no provisional header but still there are no cookie, too.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VL92C.jpg)
Plus, network type change to preflight. Before, it was xhr.

How can I solve this cookie problem?

My login code is like this.

[useLocalLogin.js] -custom hook
`

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useRecoilState, useSetRecoilState } from "recoil";
import {
  authenticated,
  loginInputsSelector,
  loginValidationMessage,
} from "../store";
import axios from "axios";
import { validateLoginInput } from "../util";
import { validateErrorMessage } from "../constants";

const useLocalLogin = () => {
  const setIsAuthenticated = useSetRecoilState(authenticated);
  const [loginInputs, setLoginInputs] = useRecoilState(loginInputsSelector);
  const [errorField, setErrorField] = useState({
    email: false,
    password: false,
  });
  const [validationMessage, setValidationMessage] = useRecoilState(
    loginValidationMessage
  );

  const login = async () => {
    const { errorField, errorMessage } = validateLoginInput(loginInputs);
    setErrorField(errorField);
    setValidationMessage(errorMessage);
    if (!errorMessage) {
      const response = axios
        .post("http://3.36.78.249/auth/sign-in", loginInputs)
        .then((res) => {
          if (res.status === 400) {
            setErrorField({ email: true, password: true });
            setValidationMessage(validateErrorMessage.loginFailed);
            return res;
          } else {
            setIsAuthenticated(true);
          }
        });

      return { response };
    }
  };

  return { errorField, validationMessage, login, setLoginInputs };
};

export default useLocalLogin;
```

`

[LoginForm.jsx]
`

```
import React from "react";
import LoginButton from "./LoginButton";
import { FormErrorMessage, FormTextField } from "../common";
import { FormField } from "../../styled";
import { useLocalLogin } from "../../hooks";
import {
  emailFieldProps,
  localLoginButtonProps,
  passwordFieldProps,
} from "../../constants";

const authType = "login";

function LoginForm() {
  const { errorField, validationMessage, login, setLoginInputs } =
    useLocalLogin();

  const onBlurTextField = ({ target }) => {
    const { value, name } = target;
    const textFieldInput = { [name]: value };
    setLoginInputs(textFieldInput);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form>
        <FormField>
          <FormTextField
            {...emailFieldProps(authType)}
            onBlur={onBlurTextField}
            isValid={!errorField.email}
          />
          <FormTextField
            {...passwordFieldProps(authType)}
            onBlur={onBlurTextField}
            isValid={!errorField.password}
          />
        </FormField>
        <FormErrorMessage
          message={validationMessage}
          style={{ padding: "6px 0 16px" }}
        />
        <LoginButton loginFn={login} buttonProps={localLoginButtonProps} />
      </form>
    </>
  );
}

export default LoginForm;
```

`

Please help me... Thank you

1. check extension- no problem
2. check cache using developer tool- no provisional header but still no cookie

Comment: In login request on frontend , set withCredentials : true  and then in backend on cors middleware add origin : true and credentials : true like

Comment: Solved problem! Thank you :) I got cookie in my network response. But sadly cookie is not in my application..

Comment: Is your cookie httpOnly ?